# Using Ber(p) to construct Uni(0,1) and back to Ber(r)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider having a coin with probabilities $p$ for heads(H) and $1-p$ for tails(T) (I guess we would require $0<p<1$). I want to construct a $Ber(r)$ random variable where $r \in [0,1]$. My thought was to construct at first $Ber(1/2)$ random variable as follows:
$X_i=1$ if the event HT happens before TH and $X_i=0$ if TH happens before HT where the events are made by flipping the coin until we either TH or HT in a row. Then $X_i \sim Ber(1/2)$.

Let the $X_i$ be independent and let $Y = \sum_{i=1} \frac{X_i}{2^i}$ then I want to show that $Y \sim Uni[0,1]$. Well since the binary fractions are uniquely determined for every number except those who are can be represented with finite number of zeros or ones. But I guess since those number can be represented in two ways that the set of those events, call it $M$ and $M \subset \mathbf{Z}\cap(0,1)$, thus $M$ is a null set with respect to the Lebesgue measure and therefore since we have equal probabilites of each of these binary fractions we get that
$$Y\sim Uni[0,1]$$
Now if we define the random variable

$$ Z = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad Y \leq r \\
    0 & \quad \text{else}
  \end{array} \right.$$
Then $Z\sim Ber(r)$.
Well my question is whether this arguement is valid, or do I need some arguement such as that the numbers having two binary fraction representation are uniformly distributed on the interval and if the other arguements are valid.

Comment: The argument is valid. Note that it is not necessary to actually compute $Y$, only an approximation sufficient to determine whether $Y\leqslant r$ or $Y\gt r$, and that this needs only a (random and almost surely) finite number of Bernoullis.

Comment: and this is very important when you want to actally make simulations.